# Cell formating based on other cell value google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have 2 sheets the first one is Orders and second one is the ShippingDoc.

At Shipping doc, I have Cell C2. In that cell I choose/write  ID from range of A7:A from Orders.

Is there a way if I choose example ID 1 at C2 then automatically A7 at Orders to change background to green. Also if I change the ID to 2 the A8 to be green and to not delete the A7 color.

Comment: So, just to clarify, you want to be able to change the color of A7 in orders if you write ID 1 and change also the color of A8 in Orders if your ID is 2 right?

Comment: Yes if i write ID 1 at C2  then A7 to be green then if change id to 2 at C2 and A8 to be green also to keep the A7 green too

Comment: your last sentence is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better way of achieving this using Apps Script. Go to *tools->Script editor* and there use the following code (explained on the comments in the code):

```js
  // Update everytime the value on C2 changes
  function onEdit() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    // Get C2 value
    var C2value = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("ShippingDoc").getRange('C2').getValue();
    
    // If input value is higher than 0
    if(C2value>0){
      // Ofset to set the background after A7
      var number = C2value+6;
      // Set background color of appropiate cell
      spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Orders").getRange('A'+number+'').setBackground('green');
    }
    
  }
```

Check out more information about how to do amazing things in sheets with simple scripts [HERE](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything or if you did  not understand something.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=(REGEXMATCH(""&INDIRECT("ShippingDoc!C2"), ""&A1))*(A1<>"")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: to keep ID 1 green is **not** possible with conditional formatting